# Heroku: Can staging environment be accessible for only some people?

Tags: heroku, devops

Let's assume I have **staging** and **production** versions of my application. I want **staging** version should be accessible only to specific people like developers, testers. Do we have that kind of configuration on Heroku like deployed address can be only accessed by users have some key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing like this in the Heroku product at this time.  You would need to handle this as part of your application in some way.

Comment: Oh too bad. Thank you anyway.